# How can I do this with a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What I'm trying to do is take an `IEnumerable` of an object that has 2 fields and find how many of one of the fields is associated with only 1 of the first.

In other words, the setup is like

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Baz
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }    
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        List<Baz> bazzers = new List<Baz>() {

            new Baz { Foo = "A", Bar = 1 },
            new Baz { Foo = "A", Bar = 3 },
            new Baz { Foo = "B", Bar = 1 },
            new Baz { Foo = "B", Bar = 1 },
            new Baz { Foo = "C", Bar = 2 },
            new Baz { Foo = "C", Bar = 2 },
            new Baz { Foo = "D", Bar = 1 },
            new Baz { Foo = "D", Bar = 1 }

        };

        // WANTED: An IEnumerable<Baz> that is like

       // { Bar = 1, LoyalFoos = 2 }, (because both "B" and "D" are paired only with 1)
       // { Bar = 2, LoyalFoos = 1 }, (because "C" is paired only with 2)
       // { Bar = 3, LoyalFoos = 0 }  (because there is no Foo that is paired only with the Bar 3)


    }

}
```

Is there a nice way to do this with LINQ?

Comment: could you explain a little better what you want? What "paired" means?

Comment: i think he means (as his example shows) how many of "row2" does the object in "row1" relates to

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I mean in the sense that a `Baz` is a pairing of (or a relationship between)  a `Foo` and a `Bar`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you want for output. Maybe something like this if you're looking for the count of loyal foos for each bar:

```
    var result = bazzers
        .Select(bazzer => bazzer.Bar)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(bar => new
        {
            Bar = bar,
            LoyalFoos = bazzers
                .GroupBy(bazzer => bazzer.Foo)
                .Count(group => group.All(bazzer => bazzer.Bar == bar))
        });
```

Or if you want a grouping of each loyal foo given bar:

```
    var result = bazzers
        .Select(bazzer => bazzer.Bar)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(bar => new
        {
            Bar = bar,
            LoyalFoos = bazzers
                .GroupBy(bazzer => bazzer.Foo)
                .Where(group => group.All(bazzer => bazzer.Bar == bar))
                .SelectMany(group => group)
        });
```